# What's the difference between readOnly=true and TransactionType Never?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I'm using Spring to handle my transactions.Actually,I saw an example in which we have a method that made find on a table using default transactionn aspect @RequiredNew with readOnly=true.

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public E findAll(E entity) {
        return repository.save(entity);
    }
```

My question is why not making like this and what's the difference ?

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NEVER)
    @Override
    public Iterable<E> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
```

Comment: What does the javadoc say? Have you read it? None of the code snippets makes sense.

Comment: For Transaction Never It said Execute non-transactionally .For Readonly it said  A boolean flag that can be set to {@code true} if the transaction is
  * effectively read-only .What i'm asking is about performance issue.

Comment: Performance is irrelevant. None of the code snippets make any sense. Start by writing correct code. Then when you have something working correctly, See if you have a performance problem. Then, if you have one, measure to make sure where it comes from. Then wonder about how you might make that specific part faster.

Comment: My question is suppose i have a findAll request to database for example.What's better use readOnly=true or make the method non transactional? It's simple as that.

Comment: You need a transaction to use JPA. End of story. If your findAll method really is read-only (i.e. it actually finds entities and doesn't save any like it does in your code), then you can use readOnly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readOnly` property tells both Hibernate and your database that you don't want any possible changes to be committed. This sets `FlushMode.NEVER` in the current Hibernate Session. Even if you call a `save()` method, no changes will happen in your database.

`Propagation.NEVER` means that Spring will execute the operation *non-transactionally*, and will throw an Exception if a transaction exists. This ensures that no transaction will be created.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Propagation.html